# Computing non-central moments and normalizer of a quartic exponential distribution

Tags: moments, exponential-family, numerical-integration

Consider a random variable $X$ which has quartic exponential distribution: $$X \sim P(x)=\frac{1}{Z}e^{ax + bx^2 + cx^3 + dx^4}$$ How can one compute $Z$ or non-central moments $E X^k$ given that they exist? As far as I understand, there are no closed-form formulas for these quantities, but is there a good numerical procedure for estimating them?

Since I'm very far from being any kind of expert in numerical integration, I'm open to any suggestions that will get the job done with reasonable precision.

Comment: How do you propose using numerical integration, given non-numerical  $a, b, c$ and $d$?

Comment: I meant I have values for $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$. Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: What are they ?

Comment: I need a procedure to compute moments for arbitrary $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$, given that they define a proper distribution. The  constraint on them is, I believe, $(d < 0) \lor (d = 0) \land (b < 0)$.